# Autoincremento em componentes do Android

Tags: java, android

Bom pessoal, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
            if (bolaPreta == 1) {
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circpreto);
            }
            if (bolaPreta == 2) {
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circpreto);
                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circpreto);
            }
            if (bolaPreta == 3) {
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circpreto);
                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circpreto);
                img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circpreto);
            }
```

Há alguma possibilidade de trocar esse tipo de programação, para algo que faz auto incremento nos componentes declarados?

Por exemplo: Algo que fosse incrementando o `img`: `img1`, `img2`, `img3` ... `imgN`.

Comment: Quando `bolaPreta == 1` o que é atribuído a img2 e img3? Qual é o valor máximo de imagens(imgN)?

Comment: O valor de imagens máximo é 10. Quando a bolaPreta == 1 não é atribuída nada, as img2 e img3 não aparecem na interface.

Answer (score 1):

Tente algo assim:

```
ImageView[] views = new ImageView[] { img1, img2, img3 /*, ..., imgN*/ };

for (int i = 0; i < bolaPreta; i++) {
    views[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circpreto);
}
```

Talvez faça sentido colocar algo parecido com isso logo depois (observe que agora é branco, e não preto):

```
for (int i = bolaPreta; i < views.length; i++) {
    views[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_circbranco);
}
```

Comment: Ainda não tive a oportunidade de testar, mas quando ocorrer darei o meu feedback!